# Can vmlinux be loaded into memory of virtual machine -- what comes before it?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, embedded-linux

On Wikipedia about vmlinux output file after compilation is done

> vmlinux is a statically linked executable file that contains the Linux kernel in one of the object file formats supported by Linux, which includes Executable and Linkable Format, Common Object File Format and a.out.

So it is `a.out` file after compilation.

If I want to load it in memory then what comes before it? like  primary boot loader,U-boot , and what is device tree and DTB files on this page its says https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192640/how-do-i-tell-which-device-tree-blob-dtb-file-im-using

> When U-Boot executes the boot command, it provides a memory address for the kernel and a memory address for the device tree blob. Therefore, prior to this command, it must load these files into memory. Based on the messages you provided we see that two files failed to be loaded from the eMMC/SD card:

Does every running linux installed system how many device tree blob are there. Is it only one?

Comment: vmlinux is not the file which is running when Linux kernel starts.

Comment: @0andriy what about vmlinuz?

Comment: It's a compressed version of stripped version of vmlinux The real image has more code around it. In any case, if you know how to run, you may run even vmlinux.

Comment: @0andriy which resource I should refer to?do I know please can u tell?

Comment: @0andriy is this resource good for learning systems programming and kernel https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/762bb78d89d1359c01a7ecee37e3f8132a48c1ce