# passing 2d array after specific "i" index to function so just pass specific one d from 2d array

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, function-declaration

I have a function `print` that accepts char pointer or 1D array but in calling function I have 2d array And I want to pass specific i-th index in array arr[i][j] so I can print all the j `int` elements of that passed i-th index of `arr[i][j] array

this is what I tried

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void print(int n,char *arr)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%c",arr[i]);
    
    }
    printf("\n");

}

int main()
{
    char arr[3][3]={{1,3,1},{2,1,2},{2,3,3}};
    char *n=(char *)arr+1;
    print(3,arr[1]);
    //or
    print(3,arr+1); 
    
    return 0;

}
```

in main I am trying to pass specific i-th index which `is 1` and print all the j-th elements in print function. I could not get it to work

Comment: no errors but simple received array is empty

Comment: printed spaces and nothing

Comment: ...or use `printf("%c", arr[i] + '0')`, or change `%c` to `%d`.

Comment: @user3121023 ok it worked but why passing like `print(3,arr+1)` gives me `warning: passing argument 2 of ‘print’ from incompatible pointer type` but this goes away when do `print(3,(char *)(arr+1))`. please can u explain a little bit

Comment: @user786 `arr+1` (or `arr+i`, or just `arr` when it is not the operand `sizeof` or `&`) has type `char (*)[3]` but the function parameter has type `char *`. That is why you get the warning.

Comment: @IanAbbott I dont know what is `char (*)[3]`? can u please add something what its called with name added like `(*some_name)` I think its function pointer but dont know what is `char (*)[3]`

Comment: @user786 `char (*)[3]` means "pointer to array length 3 of char". (The parentheses are required here because `char *[3]` would mean "array length 3 of pointer to char".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters there is no sense to output integers like 1, 2, 3 as characters using the conversion specifier `%c`.

Either output them as indeed integers using the conversion specifier `%d` or convert them to characters using expressions like `arr[i] + '0'` or initialize the source array using characters as '1', '2', '3'.

For this call

```
print(3,arr+1);
```

the compiler will issue a message because the type of the argument expression `arr + 1` `char ( * )[3]` differs from the type of the corresponding function parameter `char *`.

You need to write either

```
print(3,arr[1]);
```

or

```
print(3, *( arr + 1 ) );
```

In this case the expressions `arr[1]` and `*( arr + 1 )` yield a character array of the type `char[3]` that is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element of the type `char *`.

Comment: does this `char ( * )[3]` have a name? can I create variables of type `char ( * )[3]` and use them can u please show me that

Comment: @user786 For example char ( *p )[3] = arr + 1; Then you can call your function like print( 3, *p );

Comment: @user786 No, it is pointer to array (not pointer to first element of array).

Comment: thanks for help. can u please if u know linux embedded development? i have a question. i was looking for the answer for quite long

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68312153/can-vmlinux-be-loaded-into-memory-of-virtual-machine-what-comes-before-it

Comment: @user786 t is a pointer to an array of the type char[3]. Dereferencing the pointer you will get the pointed array that used in expressions (with rare exceptions) is converted to pointer to its first element as it is shown above print( 3, *p );